# How to establish parent child relationship between 2 tables

Tags: mysql

i Have 2 tables coursemaster and course subject under course master i have 2 columns course code and course name and under course subject i have course code and subject code.My aim is if i delete course code in course master it should not delete and if i update it should get updated and reflect in course subject.pls tell me how to write query for this.

My course master table structure

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
     1  id  int(11)         No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Fulltext Fulltext
     2  course_code varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values  Primary Primary  Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Fulltext Fulltext
     3  course_name varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Fulltext Fulltext
```

course subject structure

```
Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
 1  id  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT   Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values  Primary Primary  Unique Unique   Index Index    Show more actions More
 2  course_code varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Show more actions More
 3  subject_code    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Show more actions More
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Course
(
id int NOT NULL,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Subject
(
id int NOT NULL,
code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
CourseId int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseId) REFERENCES Course(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems that you need to establish a relation between tables.

```
ALTER TABLE 'master' ADD PRIMARY KEY ('course_code');
ALTER TABLE 'subject' ADD FOREIGN KEY ('course_code') REFERENCES 'master' ('course_code');
```